# Adjust paddings like Microsoft Word

Tags: javascript, html

Here I want to simulate the **margin-adjustment style** of Microsoft Word. That is, changing one side of the margin individually, and the other side doesn't move. Like this:
[image]

I create a "paper, and it nests a div with some content, like this:

```
<div id="paper">   /*width:740px*/
 <div id="myDiv">  /*width:740px*/
  <p>bla bla bla bla</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Additionally, I add an slider to change the padding-left and padding-right of `myDiv`:

```
<input type="range" class="range"  min="0" max="100" step="1" value="0" onChange="show(1,this)"></div>
<input type="range" class="range"  min="0" max="100" step="1" value="0" onChange="show(2,this)"></div>
```

This is the function:

```
function show(index,obj){            
    var width =740;        
    var size = obj.value;
    var inn = document.getElementById("myDiv");

     for (var i in inn) {
         switch(index)
        {
            case 1:
                inn[i].style.paddingLeft=size+"px";
                width = width-size;
                inn[i].style.width=width+"px";
                break;
            case 2:
                inn[i].style.paddingRight=size+"px";
                inn[i].style.width=width-size+"px";
                width = width-size;
                break;

        }   
    }            
 }
```

It seems works not good when the 2 sliders are assigned values at the same time. Could you help me to solve this problem?

PS: - I should use switch here because I omitted other irrelevant parts, which need a switch. And, why I use `padding-left`/`padding-right` in the code is because I want to keep the border of inner div `myDiv` unchanged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `document.getElementsByClassName("myDiv")` but there seem to be no class of that name set on your div, only an id.

Try this:

```
function show(index,obj){            
    var width =740;        
    var size = obj.value;
    var inn = document.getElementById("myDiv");

    switch(index)
    {
        case 1:
            inn.style.paddingLeft=size+"px";
            width = width-size;
            inn.style.width=width+"px";
            break;
        case 2:
            inn.style.paddingRight=size+"px";
            inn.style.width=width-size+"px";
            width = width-size;
            break;

    }   
}
```

If you want the "paper" to have the same width after adding padding (then you don't have to recalculate the width each time), you can use:

```
#myDiv {
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

in your CSS style rules. Which in case would lead to this instead:

```
function show(index,obj){            
    var size = obj.value;
    var inn = document.getElementById("myDiv");

    switch(index)
    {
        case 1:
            inn.style.paddingLeft=size+"px";
            break;
        case 2:
            inn.style.paddingRight=size+"px";
            break;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Very precise! Thanks a lot!